Add Optional Variables in Groupby Function Pandas
Let's say I have the following data frame, and I want to have var_a be optional, so that if it is not supplied there will not be a default value; it will only group by the variable vehicle. How do I do that? I was trying to figure out with **Kwargs, but I am not getting it.
d = {'col1': ['1', '2', '2', '4', '5'], 'vehicle': ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike'], 'eng': [2, 2, 6, 6, 0], 'id' : ['1','2','3','4','5']}
df_attempt = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def new_fun(df, var_a):

   return df.groupby(['vehicle', var_a], as_index = False)['id'].count()

new_fun(df_attempt, 'col1') 

Trying with **kwargs:
def new_fun(df, **kwargs):
    var_a = kwargs.get('var_a', None)
    return df.groupby(['vehicle', var_a], as_index = False)['id'].count()

new_fun(df_attempt, 'col1')  
``


Be explicit, provide a default value and test if the default was provided:
def new_fun(df, var_a=None):
    group = 'vehicle' if var_a is None else ['vehicle', var_a]
    return df.groupby(group, as_index = False)['id'].count()

out = new_fun(df_attempt)

Output:
  vehicle  id
0    bike   1
1     car   2
2   truck   2

If None is possibly a valid column name, you could use a special default (pandas uses sep=_NoDefault.no_default for example in read_csv).
Here is a more generic example, that also accepts lists of  columns:
from pandas._libs.lib import no_default
def new_fun(df, var_a=no_default):
    group = ['vehicle']
    if var_a is not no_default:
        group.extend(var_a if isinstance(var_a, list) else [var_a])
    return df.groupby(group, as_index = False)['id'].count()

new_fun(df_attempt)
new_fun(df_attempt, 'col1')
new_fun(df_attempt, ['col1', 'eng'])


Thanks so much for this! This is perfect! So what I am really going for is what you answer in the second example where you have multiple grouping variables that are optional, like col1 and eng. Is the second example going to be the best way of doing this, if that is what I want?
